# Importing http in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a small TypeScript application for NodeJS, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Here is a sample

```
/// <reference path="./typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
'use strict';

// Import http from Node
// ES6 way of writing it: import * as http from "http";
import http = require('http');

http
 .createServer((req, res) => {
   res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
   res.end("<h1>Hello NodeJS</h1>")
 })
.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server running on port 3000"));
```

In ES5 I would get http into the application by writing `const http = require('http');`, however in that way Visual Studio Code does not give me code completion. When I write the ES6 version `import * as http from "http"` I get code completion in VS Code, but Node doesn't run.

So I ended up with `import http = require('http');`, however I'm not sure if that is an acceptable way.

Is there some way I can just use the ES6-version?

Answer (score 0):

> however in that way Visual Studio Code does not give me code completion

`import` are const anyways so you don't need `const`

> When I write the ES6 version import * as http from "http" I get code completion in VS Code, but Node doesn't run.

You need to compile with `--target es5` for it to transpile down to modules that node understands.

## Solution

Just use `import`, it behaves like `const` from TypeScript's perspective anyways.